# Is MongoDB database vulnerable to malicious npm packages?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, security, xss, sql-injection

are node js applications that use a MongoDB database vulnerable to malicious npm packages? if so, what security threat is mongoDB immune to? (i.e. cross site scripting?)

Answer (score 1):

If you install unverified packages in your application, your application is vulnerable regardless of which database it is using.

MongoDB server does not provide a web interface hence XSS is not a vulnerability class applicable to it.